# Are there any noticeable differences if a grey scale image is converted to RGB?

Tags: website-design, images, rgb, color-profile, grayscale

Browsing through the archives I didn't see this question asked before after reviewing the tags [color-profile](/questions/tagged/color-profile), [rgb](/questions/tagged/rgb), [grayscale](/questions/tagged/grayscale) but I am wondering if there are any visual differences if an image that was once a gray scale profile is converted to RGB.

To explain what I'm doing I'm currently working on an image based website design that needs an app to assist in the upload process so when I check the image's profile with ImageMagick to convert CMYK images to RGB I noticed the greyscale profile and I couldn't tell any major differences on the conversion and I wanted to know if there were any side effects when converting grayscale to RGB?

When trying to figure out why to use grayscale if there aren't any distinct changes then is there any reason to use grayscale other then to get an image to black and white?  Wouldn't a grayscale profile produce a smaller file size than RGB?

Comment: Oh. This is something I should check, but probably the gray's "black" could be interpreted as the "not so black" value in RGB (simmilar as the c0m0y0k100)

Comment: Well Im trying to also consider the compression of images and I've spent a lot of time reading on terminal based conversion processes so this is something I need to figure before I step into the next phase.

Comment: One aditional mode to explore is a Grayscale image converted to indexed RGB one.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is gamma correction. Consider that greyscale is essentially a special case of indexed RGB where the index palette is implicit and that all greyscale images are RGB where R=G=B upon render (excepting monochrome displays and exotic hardware).